# How to get path of the image choose from gallery in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, image, ipad

I have Five buttons.On each button action.I have open gallery and choose an image.But the problem is on each button action same path is coming.

```
UIImage* image = [info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

NSString * imageName = @"Myimage.png";


NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString* fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
 NSLog(@"fullPathToFile=%@",fullPathToFile);    //important line

[imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:NO];
```

Comment: save image with different name

Answer (score 1):

Set global variable initially int countVal = 1;

```
NSString * imageName = [NSString stringWithformat:@"%d.png",countVal]; // Imgae_name set here
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
 NSLog(@"fullPathToFile=%@",fullPathToFile);    //important line
[imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:NO];
count +=1; // Increment count here
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something, but it looks like you're using the same name for the image each time:  Myimage.png.  Every time the image will be saved inside the documents directory with that same name.  Maybe add a tag to each button and use that to distinguish each of the 5 different images?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code which just edited to you answer
The problem is only with saving image name,try to save it with different name
The below code will help you in saving image with diffrent name
note: put the tag value to diffrent button(5 buttons) and call bello method in its target

```
      -(void)saveImage:(UIButton*)sender{
      UIImage* image = [info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    
    NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    
    NSString * imageName =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Myimage%d.png",sender.tag];
    
    
    NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    
    NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    
    NSString* fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
    NSLog(@"fullPathToFile=%@",fullPathToFile);    //important line
    
    [imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:NO];
}
```

by this you can save image with different name

Answer (score 0):

May be it will helpful for u

```
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
imageView.image= [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
NSData *webData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image);
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *localFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:png];
[webData writeToFile:localFilePath atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"localFilePath.%@",localFilePath);

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:localFilePath];
```

OR

Use this code

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"];

imageView.image= [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
NSData *webData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image);
[imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];  

 NSLog(@"localFilePath.%@",localFilePath);
```

If you still get it empty then try by checking if NSData is created properly

```
NSLog(@"webData.%@",webData);
```

OR

Try this: I hope defnetly it will be be helpful to you

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
  {
   UIImage *img = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
  //you can use UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage for the original image

  //Now, save the image to your apps temp folder, 

    NSString *path = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"upload-image.tmp"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
   //you can also use UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img,1); for jpegs
   [imageData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

   //now call your method
  [self uploadMyImageToTheWebFromPath:path];
}
```